# What is the default encryption algorithm used by Azure TDE?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, tde

Azure SQL Server offers Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) by default, with the flick of a virtual switch:

[image: Azure TDE]

There is no option to select an algorithm and I am not using "[Bring Your Own Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#bring-your-own-key)".

Which encryption algorithm is being used and what is the key length?

All articles I find such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=azuresqldb-current) have circular references to one another with no clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this in your SQL Azure database

```
select * from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
```

you should see the encryption algorithm being used and the key length.

In my case I have TDE enabled in one of my databases and I can see that the key_algorithm is AES and the key_lenght is 256.

Answer (score 1):

It is **AES 256**

See this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql?tabs=azure-portal